# Running non-blocking coroutines within the main thread

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

We've a special use case and I need help to find out, if we can solve our problem with Kotlin's coroutines or if we have to rely on CompletableFutures.

Basically, we write plugins for a server that is single threaded itself. This means, we can use different hooks to add logic and this logic always runs within the main thread that must not be blocked. In addition, when using the server's API, we must be within the main thread, because the given methods aren't thread safe.

To get this working with asynchronous code, we've used the server's scheduler to spawn a producer/consumer-system that runs asynchronous tasks in the background and *synchronizes* the results back to the server's main thread. The implementation shouldn't be that important, so here is just an example of how this looks like in practice:

```
// execute hook that runs when a user on the server runs a command
override fun execute(sender: CommandSender, args: Array<out String>) {
    // call comes from the main thread
    db.fetchBalance(sender.name)
        // fetchBalance runs asynchronous code without blocking
        // the current thread by utilizing a consumer/producer system
        .thenAccept {
            // the CompletableFuture is resolved after completion

            // here we are in the main thread again, so that we can access
            // server methods in a thread safe manner
            sender.sendMessage("Your balance: $it")
        }
}
```

Now my question is, if the above example can be replaced with Kotlin code that makes it more readable, like async/await in JavaScript. To remember, in JavaScript we can do this:

```
async function onBalanceRequest(client, name) {
  let balance = await db.fetchBalance(name);
  client.sendMessage("Your money: " + balance);
}
```

I've asked a similar question regarding to async/await some days ago, that led to a solution that could look like this:

```
private fun onBalanceRequest(sender: CommandSender) {
    // call comes from the main thread
    GlobalScope.launch {
        // here we are within a new thread
        val money = db.fetchBalance(sender.name).join()
        // here we are within the same thread, which is
        // not the main thread, so the code below isn't safe
        sender.sendMessage("Your balance: $money")
    }
}
```

As described in the comments, the problem is, that after "waiting for the future", the code runs in the coroutine's thread. So my question is, if we can achieve something like I've described with coroutines or if they were simply not made for this use case. I've read about the possibility to specify a thread for the spawned coroutine, but then this thread would be blocked, so that won't work.

If CompletableFutures are the only way to *solve* this problem, we will stick with them, but I wanted to give coroutines a try, since they look better to write and to handle than CompletableFutures.

Thanks

Comment: *we must be within the main thread, because the given methods aren't thread safe.* -- Fyi a method being not "thread safe" does not mean it must be called on the main thread. Also, with coroutines you do not specify a thread for it to run on, but a dispatcher/context

Comment: You are right. It means, that objects and their methods are not designed to be used by multiple threads and since the server runs within the main thread (which we can call server thread, if you want), we have to access them from the same thread that calls our methods.

Comment: Well with coroutines you can do exactly what you are doing in your first code snippet. You execute code on "not main thread" (not blocking, but suspending) e.g. with `launch(Dispatchers.IO)` and when that is done you continue on the thread that you started on without requiring you to switch back manually. You can specify the Main dispatcher to be the one where coroutines are run on initially

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, I don't really get your point. If I replace `launch` by `launch(Dispatchers.IO)`, nothing really changes. The code still runs within the spawned thread and not within the thread, where the initial call came from.

Comment: So what you want is for the main thread to start a coroutine, that coroutine runs on a background thread, and when it's finished, it calls some method (possibly passing in a value calculated in the coroutine) and the method which it calls is executed back on the main thread?

Comment: Ok well IIRC you can run on Dispatchers.Unconfined if you want to run the coroutine on the calling thread, see https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/docs/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.md#dispatchers-and-threads

Comment: @YoniGibbs yes, like in the first snippet. 
@TimCastelijns when using `Unconfined`, the `.join()` call on the `CompletableFuture` blocks the calling thread and so the main thread, what freezes the server until the future is resolved.

Comment: Could you maybe convert the coroutine to a `CompletableFuture` then call `thenAcceptAsync`, passing in an executor that would run the code on your main thread?  e.g.

`CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).future {`
`    // In background thread - all code in here can use coroutine goodness`
`    "some return value"`
`}.thenAcceptAsync({`
`    // In main thread supplied by myMainThreadExecutor)`
`}, myMainThreadExecutor)`

(Sorry, can't figure out how to format the code in a comment to make it readable.)

Comment: Well, the `db.fetchBalance` already is a CompletableFuture. I did not test your code, but it looks like it will end with something like my first snippet and then it won't be an improvement at all. Or am I getting you wrong? @YoniGibbs

Comment: No, you're right, it will be quite similar.  But the advantage of it is that the code inside the `future` block can all use coroutines.  So if that code ends up calling a complex series of other functions, all of which you want to be non-blocking, you can write it all in a much more idiomatic fashion using coroutines rather than having lots of completable futures.

Comment: Thank you, but I guess this attempt will not make anything better in our use cases, since my idea was to reduce boilerplate/nesting and allow a better exception handling. However, if our requirements are _too special_, CompletableFutures are okay for now.

Answer (score 3):

Try `withContext` function. Wrap your code in it and it will be executed in desired context.

For Example:

```
withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
    //This will run in Main Thread
}
```

You can replace `Dispatchers.Main` with CoroutinesContext of your choice

*Note: `withContext` function is "suspending" function and it must be executed only in `Coroutine Scope`*

Answer (score 1):

**Executing Immediately**

What if you do need it to execute immediately? For this, you can use

```
Dispatchers.Main.immediate
```

Executes coroutines immediately when it is already in the right context

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    launch(Dispatchers.Main.immediate) {
        log("A")
    }

    log("B")
}
```

Print

```
OUTPUT:
// A
// B
```

Comment: You should cite your sources : https://medium.com/@trionkidnapper/launching-a-kotlin-coroutine-for-immediate-execution-on-the-main-thread-8555e701163b